# Evaluating multiple columns with a select case statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to evaluate multiple pieces of information from various columns then output value if the answers meet certain conditions.

I have tried doing an extended select case statement but I know my syntax is wrong or it is not possible to do it the way I am trying to do it. It also throwing the error "type mismatch". Not the full code but a portion.

```
Dim EJ As String
Dim EL As String
Dim EX As String
Dim EZ As String
Dim EG As String

EJ = GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EJ"))
EL = GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EL"))
EX = GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EX"))
EZ = GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EF"))
EG = GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EG"))

Select Case EJ And EL And EX And EZ
   Case GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EJ")) = "YES" And _
        GetCellValue(.Cells(i, EL")) "YES" And _
        GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EX")) = "YES" And _
        GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EZ")) = "YES"
           .Cells(i, "FI") = Done
```

I would like to output the word done in a column if the conditions are met.

Comment: `Select Case` is probably not the best choice for this - a regular `If...ElseIf...Else` would be fine.  BTW you're not using the variables you created and populated in your `Case` ?

Comment: @Tim this is a small portion of the code. I have about 20 other conditionals which is why I went with the case. Please explain: I thought I was calling in the variables using the select case

Comment: You can't combine multiple variables like that (unless you really intend to `And` them all together to a single expression) you're basically trying to evaluate `"YES" And "YES" And "YES" And "YES"` which as you've seem just gives you a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop can be avoided with Excel Formulas. For example if `i` is from 2 to 9 :

```
.Range("FI2:FI9").Formula = "=IF(AND(EJ2=""YES"", EL2=""YES"", EX2=""YES"", EZ2=""YES""), ""Done"", """")"
.Range("FI2:FI9").Value = .Range("FI2:FI9").Value  ' optional to convert the formulas to values
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select Case` is probably not the best choice for this - a regular `If...ElseIf...Else` would be fine

```
 If EJ="YES" And EL="YES" And EX="YES" And EZ="YES" Then
     .Cells(i, "FI") = "Done" '<< added quotes here
 Else
     'etc etc
 End If
```

This might be significantly different depending on what your other tests look like

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish your task using a filter...

```
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'change to meet your range  
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=140, Criteria1:="YES"
    .AutoFilter Field:=142, Criteria1:="YES"
    .AutoFilter Field:=154, Criteria1:="YES"
    .AutoFilter Field:=156, Criteria1:="YES"
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("Z2:Z" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.Offset(, 9).Value = "Done"
End With
```

Note: Inserting the text in a column for visible rows, without looping, is adapted from an answer by **Gary's Student** to SO question, 28609977.